# How to remove a combobox item from a listview?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make it so: once I click on the remove button, it removes combobox's text from the listview.

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sel = combobox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            repository.RemoveNumber(sel);
            view.Items.Remove(sel);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can do something like

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
                if (item.Text == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()) listView1.Items.Remove(item);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply but i get this error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.